# Mapping with Arrays Error

Tags: solidity, arrays, mapping

I'm trying to be able to add strings to the array inside the mapping but I keep getting this error on line 13:

> TypeError Member "push" not found or not visible after
> argument-dependant lookup in uint256[] storage ref.

I have looked around and evry video i have seen uses push even with the same mapped array, granted they where 1 year old.

Any ideas welcome as this has stumped me all day.
Thanks.

```
pragma solidity >= 0.6.12;
import "./SafeMath.sol";
import "./Ownable.sol";
import "./Context.sol";

contract Trail1 is Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    mapping(string => uint[]) public Pairs;
    mapping(string => mapping(string => uint256)) public Orders;
    
    function AddPair(string memory Pair, bool Create)public onlyOwner{
        if(Create == true){
            Pairs["Futures"].push(Pair);
        }else{
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have inconsistency in your types. You're trying to push a `string` (`Pair`) into an array of `uint`. Instead, you'll need to change the type of the storage memory inside `Pairs` as follows:

```
mapping(string => string[]) public Pairs;
```